# $\int_0^1 tf(2x-t)dt=\frac{1}{2}\arctan(x^2), f(1)=1$, find $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$. here $f$ is continuous.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$\int_0^1 tf(2x-t)dt=\frac{1}{2}\arctan(x^2),\ f(1)=1$, find $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$. here $f$ is continuous.

By substituting $2x-t=s$, and taking derivative, we have
$2\int_{2x-1}^{2x}f(s)ds=2f(2x-1)+\frac{x}{1+x^4}$. Let $x=1/2$, we have $2\int_0^1 f(s)ds=2f(0)+x/(1+x^4)|_{x=1/2}$. But we know just $f(1)=1$, not $f(0)$. How to pass across this obstacle?

I strongly suspect it is a wrong problem, but could not find some counterexample.

Comment: Try solving the integral equation:$$\int_0^1 t\ y(2x-t)dt=\frac12\tan^{-1}(x^2),y(1)=1 $$ by transforming into a differential equation, maybe by differentiation on both sides?

Comment: FWIW $f(t)$ can be represented using the inverse Laplace transform of $(3+2s)s^3e^{3s}/(e^s-s-1)$.