# $f(1)=1,\int_0^xtf(2x-t)dt=\frac{1}{2}\arctan(x^2)$，find $\int_1^2f(x)dx$ f is continuous.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$f(1)=1,\int_0^xtf(2x-t)dt=\frac{1}{2}\arctan(x^2)$$find $\int_1^2f(x)dx$, $f(x)$ is continuous in$(-\infty,\infty)$, $f(1)=1$

Here is the problem relevent:
[$\int_0^1 tf(2x-t)dt=\frac{1}{2}\arctan(x^2), f(1)=1$, find $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$. here $f$ is continuous.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4323578/int-01-tf2x-tdt-frac12-arctanx2-f1-1-find-int-01-fxdx-h)

Comment: How did $f$ disappear in $\int_1^xtf(2x-t)dt=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{x+1}{2}}2(2x-1)dx$?

Comment: There is the *slight* problem that the problem posed is not defined. Plug in $x=1$ to the first equation and you get $0 = \frac{\pi}{8}$ ...? This question has no solution at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's change the variable of integration to $\tau=2x-t$:
$$
\int_0^xtf(2x-t)\,dt=\int_x^{2x}(2x-\tau)f(\tau)\,d\tau. \tag{1}
$$
Now, let's differentiate both sides of
$$
\int_x^{2x}(2x-\tau)f(\tau)\,d\tau=\frac{1}{2}\arctan(x^2) \tag{2}
$$
with respect to $x$:
$$
2(2x-2x)f(2x)-(2x-x)f(x)+\int_x^{2x}2f(\tau)\,d\tau=\frac{x}{1+x^4} \\
$$
$$
\implies \int_x^{2x}f(\tau)\,d\tau=\frac{1}{2}\left(xf(x)+\frac{x}{1+x^4}\right). \tag{3}
$$
Finally, taking $x=1$ in $(3)$ gives us the desired result:
$$
\int_1^{2}f(\tau)\,d\tau=\frac{3}{4}. \tag{4}
$$